# Copying a column without repeating

Tags: python

I need to access a .txt file, it has 2 columns and a lot of rows with repeated names (using Python).
I just want to copy one of the columns without repeating the names on it, printing it on a new .txt file. I tried:

```
g = open(file,'r')
linesg = g.readlines()
h = open(file,'w+')
linesh = h.readlines()
for line in range(len(linesg)):
     if linesg[line] in linesh:
        line += 1
     else:
        h.write(linesg[line].split('\t')[1])
```

But I continue to have repeated names on the .txt file. Could anyone help me? (Yes, i'm a newbie on Python programming).
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to read and write `linesh` you need to first open it with `'r+'` instead, then read, then depending on what you want to do use `h.seek(0)` to start writing at the start of the file again, or omit that to append at the end of the file.

Comment: You cannot change `line` in a `for` loop, it'll be set back to by the loop in the next iteration.

Comment: You are also re-reading the *same file* in your code, and thus all lines in `linesg` will already be present in `linesh`. Are they meant to be *separate* files?

Comment: Yes, they are meant to be separated files, but your hints helped me and i think i did it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Rather than iterating by a generated counter, since you're reading the lines anyway, you can just iterate over the iterables from `readlines()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g = open(file,'r')
names = {}
for line in g.readlines():
    name = line.split('\t')[1] #Name is in the second tab
    names[name] = 1 #create a dictionary with the names

#names.keys() returns a list of all the names here
# change the file handle here if needed, or the original file would be overwritten. 
h = open(file,'w+')
for name in names.keys():
    h.write("%s\n"%name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sep = '\t'
lines = open('in_file.txt').readlines()
lines_out = []
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    parts = line.split(sep)
    line_out = "%s\n" %(parts[0],) # if only the first column is copied
    if line_out not in lines_out:
        lines_out.append(line_out)

h = open('out_file.txt','w')
h.writelines(lines_out)
h.close()
```

change it to parts[1] to copy the 2nd column, ..